# Django with non ORM backends

Tags: django, orm, backend, google-cloud-bigtable, non-relational-database

How to use Django with abstract non ORM backend? What to extended and override in models and views files? Unfortunately all examples on Django still assume ORM use. In my case, I try to make it work against Google BigTable using Python API

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py, in Databases you can specify the  Engine you want to use. [In django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#engine) it states:

> You can use a database backend that doesn’t ship with Django by
>   setting ENGINE to a fully-qualified path

You would need to create some BigTable-Django backend  similar to the official ones in [here](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/backends) . See that the main thing would be to use the class [BaseDatabaseSchemaEditor](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/base/schema.py) and “adapt” it to the [Python BigTable API](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/usage.html).

This is not trivial; for some simple operations and specific use case that may be feasible to do without engaging into too much developing, otherwise it could get quite tedious and some other functionalities may get “broken”. [Here you have a similar Django- with non ORM project using DataStore](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/#databases) called [Djangae](https://github.com/potatolondon/djangae), however it is not officially supported and it is for using with AppEngine as well. Anyway you may be able to get some ideas from there.